# Magento2.3: Advance Reporting shows "404"

Tags: error, magento2.3.0, advanced-reporting

I have followed all the instructions:
[Advanced Reporting](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html)


Also Magento Analytics user integration Status is “Active.”
But still facing the same error.

How can i enable Advance Reporting m using magento2.3 EC.
Is this Reporting is paid or free.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Admin and CMD line changes

```
1) run below query
delete from flag where flag_code='analytics_previous_base_url'; 
2) Go to 
 Store >> Configuration  >> General >> Advanced Reporting 
https://www.screencast.com/t/YEQbaKv9Gh first disabled and do enabled again.

3) 
Go to
Store >> Configuration >> Main Website >> General >> Web >> Base URL & Secure Base URL  (make sure admin url and default website url same)
Store >> Configuration >> Default Config >> General >> Web >> Base URL & Secure Base URL(make sure admin url and default website url same)

4) go to admin System >> Integration 
https://www.screencast.com/t/L8GrKS5L 

5) you need to click reauthorization on Magento Analytics user  
do reauthorization again for analytics use 

6) then do a cache flush 
php bin/magento c:f config 

7) n98-magerun2 sys:cron:run analytics_subscribe 
run above command to create account https://dashboard.rjmetrics.com/ 
check system.log file
for me giving below error
report.WARNING: Subscription for MBI service has been failed. An error occurred during token exchange: {"message":"Handshake request failed

So i find ip of MBI and added into whitelist IP

 how to find IP :
go to /log/access.log and search integration/tokensDialog  from that row you will find IP address

8) n98-magerun2 sys:cron:run analytics_update 

9) n98-magerun2 sys:cron:run analytics_collect_data
```

Comment: me giving below error
report.WARNING: Subscription for MBI service has been failed. An error occurred during token exchange: {"message":"Handshake request failed

when u receive this error your site was going to down or not ?

Comment: are you using something like ip restication ? or htpwd?

Comment: I have followed all the steps but Advanced Reporting not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check video and refer magento 2 devdocs, this will help you:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2N8jSiNk1io
>
> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/advanced-reporting/overview.html
>
> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Advanced-Reporting-doesn-t-work-and-there-is-an-error-404/td-p/126904

Comment: I have done already . But still shows pending and does't show advance reporting

Comment: Is your website is on https?

Comment: yes, 
https://rcg.com.pk/

Comment: flush all the cache and wait for next scheduled update (may be in 24 hours), it should work.

Comment: I have done. And wait last two days but no success.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone which its subscription status is Enabled, and have double-checked prerequisites, I post here this link regarding a possible issue in advanced reporting dashboard side:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Advanced-Reporting-doesn-t-work-and-there-is-an-error-404/m-p/145064/highlight/true#M11226